# Combination of cells with internal resistance

Tags: electric-current

[image]

Here are given two batteries $E_1,E_2$ with internal resistance $r_1$ and $r_2$ respectively. To find the potential difference between $A$ and $B$ which is $V_{AB}$, here is what is commonly done in books or online.

They assign $x$ potential to $A$ and $0$ to $B$. Then they say that the given is an *open circuit*. So current entering $A$ is $i=0$. They further divide it into  currents $i_1$ and $i_2$. By KCL, $i_1+i_2=i=0$ or $\frac{x-E_1}{r_1}+\frac{x-E_2}{r_2}=0$. From here we can easily deduce $V_{AB}$.

I actually understood the calculations but *didn't understand* how even the calculations happened. First of all, they said that *the given is an open circuit, so $i=0$*. What do they mean by open circuit? *Also if $i=0$, then NO current should even be going through $A$, isn't it? The fact they they use $i_1+i_2=0$ means one of the current is surely negative, which doesn't make any sense since that would mean $i_1$ is in one direction (let us suppose in the direction of $i$ which is left to right) and $i_2$ is in another direction. But as they said this is an open circuit, i assume they meant that it is isolated and not connected to any external component. Then how can $i_2$ pass from right to left direction? That would mean current is flowing from low potential (negative end of $E_2$ to high potential (positive end of $E_2$).*

Even though the calculations look fine i didn't at all understand why $i=0$ and even if it were i don't understand the breaking of currents from a *zero* current since that isn't making sense to me. Maybe my concepts are flawed. If so please clear my concepts.

Answer (score 2):

> What do they mean by open circuit? *Also if $i=0$, then NO current
> should even be going through $A$, isn't it?

The circuit is "open" because there is nothing connected to the left of A or the right of B. From KCL the algebraic sum of the current into node A must be zero, ergo, $i=0$.

> The fact they they use $i_1+i_2=0$ means one of the current is surely
> negative,

Since, per the above, $i=0$, then it follows from KCL that $i_{1}+i_{2}=0$.

You can also see that $i_{1}=-i_{2}$ because there is only one loop and loop current per the application of Kirchhoff's voltage law for the loop. See the loop current in the diagram below. There is no where for any current to go to the left of A or to the right of B.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Saying that, i, is zero just indicates that there is no current from an external source. That leaves just one current going around the loop. You can call it $i_1$ or $i_2$. The actual direction of positive flow will depend on the voltages of the two cells. Starting and ending at input A, I'm going to add voltage drops around the loop in the direction of $i_1$:  $E_1 + {i_1}{R_1} + {i_1}{R_2} – E_2$ = O.  If $E_1$ is greater than $E_2$, then $i_1$ is positive, and the first two terms give the voltage drop from A to B.